# page loading message appears when going back to the previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following works fine, except when I click the back button on the browser (to go back to my previous start page), the loading... message appear again. What should I do to get rid of it?
Many thanks in advance.

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
  $("#loading").show();
});
<div id="loading">loading...</div>
```

Comment: initially do you display: none; the loading div?

Comment: why are you doing this way , there are other ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(window).unload(function(){$("#loading").hide();});
```